# How to get an SVG spinner to show up before a heavy UI update?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg, vuejs3

I have a UI update in a Vue app where I update 10 [apexcharts bar charts](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-data-labels/) at once. It takes about one second for it to fully load, during which time I'd like to show an [svg spinner](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/spinner/#default-spinner). However, the normal pattern of having a `v-if="showSpinner"` on a `div` containing that spinner and setting `showSpinner.value = true;` for a `const showSpinner = ref(false);` isn't working. For example:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="showSpinner">
       [svg spinner]
    </div>
    <div>
       [10 apexcharts I'm updating at once with already existing local data]
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue';

const showSpinner = ref(false);
const state = reactive({
    dataForCharts: {},
});

const someFuncThatGetsCalledMuchLater = () => {
    showSpinner.value = true;

    // I've also tried await nextTick(); (after making this
    // function itself async) but that didn't make any difference.
    nextTick(() => {
        // some code that modifies state.dataForCharts, causing the charts to redraw    
    });
}

</script>
```

Ignoring even the code that would have to exist to set `showSpinner.value = false;` later on, which is another problem I've yet to solve, this above code doesn't show the spinner until after all of the charts have updated (which basically freezes the webpage for 1s, since my understanding is that Javascript is single-threaded).

So my two questions are:

1. How can I get this svg spinner to appear before the charts start updating and freeze the webpage?
2. Not here yet since I haven't solved (1), but how can I listen for a callback for when the charts have finished updating? I don't think directives will work for me since it seems that they are supposed to only act on the element that they're attached to, and I don't think setting `showSpinner.value = false;` inside `onUpdated(...)` would work either since that is called after every reactive update, including the changing of `showSpinner.value = true;`, so setting it false there would just instantly undo the fact that we've just set it to true.

Comment: For your first question, putting your code in a `nextTick` should help. Can you show how you implement it?

Comment: can you use a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)?

Comment: @Duannx just updated to show this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. show spinner before charts

Basically you just want to update `showSpinner` first, then trigger a redraw, and then render the charts. The simplest way would be to use `nextTick`

```js
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue';

const someFuncThatGetsCalled = async () => {
  showSpinner.value = true;
  await nextTick(); // could also pass a callback
  state.dataForCharts = someDataAndNotNullAnyMore;
}
```

`nextTick`, according to documentation, should work:

> A utility for waiting for the next DOM update flush.
>
> #### Details
>
> When you mutate reactive state in Vue, the resulting DOM updates are not applied synchronously. Instead, Vue buffers them until the "next tick" to ensure that each component updates only once no matter how many state changes you have made.
>
> `nextTick()` can be used immediately after a state change to wait for the DOM updates to complete. You can either pass a callback as an argument, or await the returned Promise.

However even though the DOM is updated, the browser may not re-render it. The subsequent js may block the rendering essentially rendering `nextTick()` useless. To deal with this issue you need to manually defer initiating the js-heavy portion until the dom renders the initial change. You can use `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` to accomplish that. Using `setTimeout` may work in some situations but is reported to behave inconsistently between browsers. It also can succumb similar issue as `nextTick` and you may need to use a higher timeout than 0 to accommodate. using nested `requestAnimationFrame` calls will wait for the browser to make the two renders before continuing, so, theoretically, is more reliable.

```js
async function nextTwik(){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        resolve()
      })
    })
  })
}
```

then you can use as:

```js
const someFuncThatGetsCalled = async () => {
  showSpinner.value = true;
  await nextTwik();
  state.dataForCharts = someDataAndNotNullAnyMore;
};
```

#### 2. How to tell if a chart got mounted

apexcharts allow passing a configuration option where you can define the events

[docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#)

```js
const chartsMounted = ref(0);

const chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    id: "bar-shart",
    events: {
      mounted(){
        chartsMounted.value ++;
      }
    },
    // animations, etc...
  },
  // dataLabels, plotOptions, xaxis, etc...
}

const someFuncThatGetsCalled = async () => {
  showSpinner.value = true;
  await nextTwik(); // defined above
  // kick off chart rendering
  state.dataForCharts = someData;
}

watch(chartsMounted, (num) => {
  if (num === 10) {
    // all 10 charts loaded
    console.log("great success");
    showSpinner.value = false
  }
})
```

As long as all charts have the mounted event listener that updates `chartsMounted` this would notify you when all charts are loaded.

#### Update

The chart event functionality was tested with Vue2 and not Vue3. ATTOW, there is a [bug in the vue3 version](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/20#issuecomment-854437408) where this doesn't work. According to the responses, apexcharts support adding the event listeners to the component using `@`, for example `@mounted`. I'm leaving the `options.events` based solution too since it reflects to the documentation.

```js
const chartsMounted = ref(0);

function onChartMounted(){
  chartsMounted.value ++;
}

const someFuncThatGetsCalled = async () => {
  showSpinner.value = true;
  await nextTwik();
  // kick off chart rendering
  state.dataForCharts = someData;
}

watch(chartsMounted, (num) => {
  if (num === 10) {
    // all 10 charts loaded
    console.log("great success");
    showSpinner.value = false
  }
})
```

template:

```html
<apex-chart :options="options" :series="series" @mounted="onChartMounted" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Daniel. Unfortunately `nextTick` doesn't seem to help. I've updated my original post to show what I've tried but the spinner (or anything I put inside the first `v-if` div, even plain text) doesn't show up until after the charts update.

Comment: For (2), I tried adding `mounted()` and `updated()` callbacks in the `events` for the chart options as you suggested but they don't seem to do anything. I just have a `console.log` inside but they never print anything, even after the chart has clearly been mounted and updated.

Comment: not sure why `nextTick` isn't working _as advertised_ here, but I've updated the answer with an alternative. Also, since the spinner doesn't use js, jank is not really an issue so removed info about loading consecutively.

Comment: re `mounted` not doing anything, are you sure you put it into the right place? if you place it inside the `options`, it will not be handled, it needs to be nested inside the `charts` object

Comment: (1) now works with `setTimeout`, thank you! For (2), yes I did put `events` inside of the `chart` field, not at the root level of the options. Unfortunately none of those events seem to fire. Not sure if it matters but I'm using https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts.

Comment: Turns out it's a known bug (https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/20#issuecomment-854437408), but luckily apexcharts emits events of the same name, so binding onto those emits `@mounted="..."` and `@updated="..."` works. Thanks again for your help, I've marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: glad it worked. I tested the apexchart by editing https://codesandbox.io/embed/qzjkzmzxoj to test the events, but now see that this was using vue2. Looks like the bug is vue3-specific

Comment: updated the answer to include information about the bug

Comment: Btw I've found a race condition: a `setTimeout` value of 0 doesn't always work on OS X Chrome (works 100% of the time on Windows Chrome). I've experimented and found a value of 20 seems to also work consistently on OS X Chrome.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was not aware of that. updated answer with note of the bug

Comment: one more update.... It seems a double `requestAnimationFrame` works better. I haven't tested on OSX, but it seems more reliable

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll do some reading on that. What do you mean by a double `requestAnimationFrame` as opposed to a single one?

Comment: it's in the update, look at the `nextTwik` definition